# Join wedge with single bond in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Is there a way to join the wedges with single bonds in chemfig in a "smooth way"?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{angle increment=30, bond join = true}
    \chemfig{-[-1](-[1])<[-3]-[-1]}
\end{document}
```

Gives out:
[image]

Is it possible to have it trim the wedge at the single bond as:

[image]

Comment: Obviously you were able to produce the result as you want. How did you create the second picture?

Comment: Chemdraw. I would rather have my figures in chemfig rather than in chemdraw for future edits if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not really an expert on `pgf` and `tikz` but I find a (partial) solution. Modifying the `chemfig` default values with `setchemfig` produces:

[image: Create modifying setchemfig]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{
         atom sep=15pt,
         cram width=3.0pt,
         cram dash width=0.75pt,
         cram dash sep=2.0pt
         bond offset=0.75pt
         bond style={line width=0.75pt}
    }
    \chemfig{-[::-30](-[::60])<[::-60]-[::60]}
\end{document}
```

I use `usetikzlibrary{decorations}` to create a custom Cram bond, based on @pisoir answer in [How to make only one part of double bond bold with chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207932/how-to-make-only-one-part-of-double-bond-bold-with-chemfig/482985).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{crambond1side}{initial}{%
    \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength]{%
        \pgfsetfillcolor{black}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.3pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.10*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{2pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.96*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-2pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.3pt}}
        \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
}
\tikzset{CramRight/.style={decorate, decoration=crambond1side}}
\tikzset{CramLeft/.style={decorate, decoration={crambond1side, mirror}}}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{crambond2sides}{initial}{%
    \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength]{%
        \pgfsetfillcolor{black}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.3pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.10*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{2pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.10*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-2pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.3pt}}
        \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
}
\tikzset{Cram2Sides/.style={decorate, decoration=crambond2sides}}

\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{
        atom sep=15pt,
        cram width=3.0pt, cram dash width=0.75pt, cram dash sep=2.0pt,
        bond offset=0.75pt,
        bond style={line width=0.75pt}
    }
    \chemfig{-[::-30](-[::+60])-[::-60,,,,CramLeft]-[::-60]}\quad
    \chemfig{-[::-30](-[::+60])-[::-60,,,,CramRight]-[::+60]}\quad
    \chemfig{-[::-30](-[::+60])-[::-60,,,,Cram2Sides](-[::-60])-[::60]}\quad
\end{document}
```

The final result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not an ideal solution, but after little bit of tweaking you might get something similar to what you want. Notice that I added the `cram width`, `line width`, and `shorten` parameters to your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{angle increment=30, bond join = true, cram width = 2.4pt}
    \chemfig{-[-1](-[1])<[-3]-[-1,,,,line width=1.5pt, shorten <=-1pt]}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]